# My under development local drupal site become very slow, how to solve?

Tags: drupal, localhost, performance

I am developing **locally** a site with **drupal** and suddenly it became very slow. The last thing I made was installing the [internationalization](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) module.

Now when I try to reach administration panel I receive:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded...

What to do now? Should I increase the maximum execution time allowed? OR could be that I have too many modules installed?

EDIT: Forgot to tell you that I am working on a PC with 2GB RAM and CPU 2.9 GHz, Windows XP + [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exceeding 60 seconds execution time is quite something - indicates that something is going quite wrong.

I'd start troubleshooting by disabling modules (physically moving them out of your modules directory) one at a time until the problem goes away. Then, add them back one at a time, until the problem returns (you'll need to re-enable them through the Modules page as you go). You should be able to quickly isolate exactly which module is causing the problem.

Since the last thing you did was to install `internationalization`, I'd start by disabling that module.

Once you've isolated the module, you can try to work out what's going wrong.

Some things to look into ...

- is your database running out of space
- Are you missing any indexes
- Do you need to "update statistics" (rebuild metrics on table contents and column distributions)

Comment: yes, it was the internationalization module that caused the problem. I solved without using it, at the moment I need only few pages translated in different language, I will manage them using custom pages, without using translation mechanism/modules

Answer (score 2):

The [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) can be useful for logging performance statistics, to help you track down the bottleneck.

Comment: thank you mattv, i will install this module in my local environment

Answer (score 0):

A [php accelerator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_accelerator) may help you get the time down a bit, there are also a number of caching options that your site can use (look in admin under performance), this may make developing more difficult but can make pages load faster.

I wouldn't increase your maximum execution time, at some stage you want to put your site wide, and if people don't get a page within a second or so they will think the site is down.

To have too many modules installed you would have to have a *lot* of modules, it is more likely that one of your modules is causing a performance bottleneck. Or something on your site like a view is causing things to slow down.  mattv's answer helps with that.

Answer (score 0):

try also activating the cache system under site settings / performance. It could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

there is a known and documented problem about massive queries getting dynamically built by the Views module when rebuilding the dynamic menu, apparently.
Unfortunately, no simple and definitive answer has been found, yet.

You can find more information [here](http://drupal.org/node/193366)  (please be aware that some answers relate to version 5).

I would really like to know how to fix this in a definitive and efficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

Use Zend Server. For detailded information check this out: http://drupal.org/node/348202#comment-3349704